# Using request to log into a website?

Tags: javascript, http, authentication, request

Hi I am trying to use request module to authenticate myself in http://www.vesseltracker.com/

How do I do that? This is what I did but it won't work

```
    let uu = 'http://*censored*:*censored*@www.vesseltracker.com/';
    request(uu, ((err, res, body) => {
        console.log(res.statusCode);
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the documentation from request available here. It looks like you are not making the request properly.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#http-authentication

Comment: What am I doing incorrectly? I tried all of those methods

Comment: It appears to me that the method you outlined above was not any of the methods detailed in the request documentation regarding where you would put the username and pw.